# Too Many Indices For Array when using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Thank you for taking time to read this question.

I am trying to plot pie charts in one row. The number of pie charts will depend on the result returned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(to_plot_arr))
labels = ['Label1','Label2','Label3','Label4']

pos = 0
for scope in to_plot_arr:
    if data["summary"][scope]["Count"] > 0:
       pie_data = np.array(db_data)
       axs[0,pos].pie(pie_data,labels=labels)
       axs[0,pos].set_title(scope)
        
    pos += 1

plt.show()
```

In the code, db_data looks like: `[12,75,46,29]`
When I execute the code above, I get the following error message:

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I've tried searching for what could be causing this problem, but just can't find any solution to it. I'm not sure what is meant by "but 2 were indexed"

I've tried generating a pie cahrt with :

```
y = np.array(db_data)
plt.pie(y)
plt.show()
```

And it generates the pie chart as expected. So, I'm not sure what is meant by "too many indices for array" which array is being referred to and how to resolve this.

Hope you are able to help me with this.

Thank You Again.

Comment: Could you please provide the full trace back? or at least the exact line where the exception is thrown at. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think this not technically and answer because I still don't know what was causing the error, but I found a way to solve my problem while still achieving my desired output.

Firstly, I realised, when I changed:
`fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(to_plot_arr))`
to:
`fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,len(to_plot_arr))`,
the figure could be drawn. So, I continued to try with other variations like `(1,2)`,`(2,1)`,`(1,3)` and always found that if ``` nrows`` or ``` ncols``` was 1, the error would come up.

Fortunately, for my use case, the layout I required was with 2 rows with the first row being one column, spanning 2 and the bottom row being 2 columns.

So, `(2,2)` fit my use case very well.

Then I set out to get the top row to span 2 columns and found out that this is best done with `GridSpec` in Matplotlib. While trying to figure out how to use `GridSpec`, I came to learn that using `add_subplot()` would be a better route with more flexibility.

So, my final code looks something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

def make_chart():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_figheight(8)
    fig.set_figwidth(10)

    # Gridspec is used to specify the grid distribution of the figure
    gs = GridSpec(2,len(to_plot_arr),figure=fig)

    # This allows for the first row to span all the columns
    r1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:])

    tbl = plt.table(
        cellText = summary_data,
        rowLabels = to_plot_arr,
        colLabels = config["Key3"],
        loc ='upper left',
        cellLoc='center'
    )
    tbl.set_fontsize(20)
    tbl.scale(1,3)    


    r1.axis('off')
    
    pos = 0
    for scope in to_plot_arr:
        if data["Key1"][scope][0] > 0:
            pie_data = np.array(data["Key2"][scope])

            # Add a chart at the specified position
            r2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,pos])
            r2.pie(pie_data, autopct=make_autopct(pie_data))
            r2.set_title(config["Key3"][scope])
        
        pos += 1
    

    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=24)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    fig.legend(labels,loc="center left",bbox_to_anchor=(0,0.25))   

    plt.savefig(savefile)

    return filename
```

This was my first go at trying to use Matplotlib, the learning curve has been steep but with a little of patients and attention to the documentation, I was able to complete my task. I'm sure that there's better ways to do what I did. If you do know a better way or know how to explain the error I was encountering, please do add an answer to this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `axs` you create in line 4 is of shape `(len(to_plot_arr),)` i.e., is `1D` array, but in the loop in lines 11 and 12 you provide it 2 indices, which tells the interpreter that it is a `2D` array, and conflicts with its actual shape.

Here is a fix:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(to_plot_arr))
labels = ['Label1','Label2','Label3','Label4']

pos = 0
for scope in to_plot_arr:
    if data["summary"][scope]["Count"] > 0:
       pie_data = np.array(db_data)
       axs[pos].pie(pie_data,labels=labels)
       axs[pos].set_title(scope)
        
    pos += 1

plt.show()
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for taking time to read my question and provide a possible solution.

I couldn't quite understand what you meant by the axs I made is a 1D array, because it is defined as "(1,len(to_plot_arr))". Thus, it should be a 2D array. 

What I found to have worked was using: "(2,len(to_plot_arr))". When I used that, then the charts could plot. 

I'll answer my question with a little bit more detail on how I went about the solution